# Visual Studio Code shows a blank screen while trying to run it as superuser

Tags: root, visual-studio-code

I tried to run VSCode as root. It actually launched successfully, but it shows just a blank screen.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I tried running it as superuser via the command `sudo code /var/www/html --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox`

Also is there a way to open VSCode as superuser automatically without typing any commands every time?

Comment: Did you intend to run `code code`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller just mistyped, nothing changes if I use "code"

Comment: You are not supposed to run it using `sudo` `sudo` is for maintenance of your system. Not for coding. Please learn and use proper safe methods to alter files. That means no `sudo`. There is zero reason to do so and there is a high risc of breaking your system. If you create a website on that system set it up properly so your user is part of the apache system.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, version 1.59 of vscode can be run as root without getting the white screen.  In another thread it was posted that the white screen when operating as root started occurring at version 1.66, and that version 1.65 still works.

Comment: There is no need and as you can install extensions from inside vscode this could mess up your system.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo -i
```

Then

```
code /var/www/html
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide some context about why you think running VSCode as super user will fix this problem. A link to documentation would be great too.